# Find $P(W_1 > 1 \cap W_2 < 1)$ where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion.

Find $P(W_1 > 1 \cap W_2 < 1)$.

I tried to do something on my own, but because I'm new to Brownian motion, I'm stuck at the beginning of the calculations.

My attempt:

Note that $W_2 = W_1 + W_2 - W_1$. Also, note that $W_1$ and $W_2 - W_1$ are independent, and $W_2 - W_1 \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Integrate  the joint density of $(W_1,W_2-W_1)$ over $\{(x,y): x<1, X+y <1\}$. The joint density of $(W_1,W_2-W_1)$  is the product of the densities of $W_1$ and $W_2-W_1$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy If it's not difficult for you, could you help me solve this problem? I'm very bad at this...

Comment: Looks like a homework problem. You have to make an effort.